# Extract words from dictionary by text and counting number of characters in R

Tags: r, dictionary

The question is:
How do count words that are extracted from the dictionary in texts?
As one may notice that in text1,  火勢 & 撲滅 are  extracted from the dictionary,
I can count the character, yes, 4.
How can I count in R?

Thanks!

Here's the code:

dict <- dictionary(list(season = c("火勢", "撲滅", "應變", "小組")))

txt <- ll$content03

season_dfm  <- dfm(txt, dictionary  = dict, verbose = FALSE)

dict_dfm <- dfm(txt, select = dict, verbose = FALSE)

cbind(season_dfm, dict_dfm)

Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents,
5 features (30.0% sparse).

```
       features
docs    season 火勢 撲滅 應變 小組
  text1      2    1    1    0    0
  text2      3    1    0    1    1
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/teEBY.jpg

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly you want to do, but the function `nchar()` counts the number of characters in a string.

Comment: I am trying to get the sums of characters that were extracted from the dictionary. In text1, 火勢 & 撲滅 were filtered from the dictionary. Nchar of 火勢 & 撲滅 are 4. My Question is, how to calculate the number of characters via R?

Comment: I understood that you want to find how many characters 火勢 & 撲滅 have combined, but you need to explain better where you want to do that in your code. `nchar("火勢")+nchar("撲滅")` will return 4, but i guess that you don't want to actually input the "火勢" by hand inside the function, so that's why i ask where do you want to do this?